# IoTDataPlane hangs indefinitely on publish() call in aws-iot-sdk-v3 (TypeScript)

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-iot, aws-sdk-js

EDIT: I found the answer. I was using the Endpoint object from '@aws-sdk/types', however I could use a string instead. Instead of:

```
  const endpoint: Endpoint = {
    hostname: 'myendpoint-ats.iot.us-east-1.amazonaws.com',
    protocol: 'mqtt',
    port:  443,
    path: ''
  };
```

I put:

```
  const endpoint: string = 'https://myendpoint-ats.iot.us-east-1.amazonaws.com';
```

and it worked just fine, published as expected and didn't hang.

/EDIT

I'm trying to publish a message to a non-reserved IoT Core MQTT topic. However when I make the publish call, it hangs indefinitely (unless I set a specific timeout, which is always hit). I believe the IAM user I am supplying has the correct permissions for publishing to an mqtt topic, although I suspect it could be a cross-account issue. Either way I would have expected a definite failure rather than a hanging endpoint.

Here is the basic code I have currently:

```
import {
  IoTDataPlane,
  IoTDataPlaneClientConfig,
  PublishCommandInput
} from '@aws-sdk/client-iot-data-plane';
import { 
  Endpoint,
  Credentials
} from '@aws-sdk/types';

export async function publishToMQTT(payload: Uint8Array, accessKeyId: string, secretKey: string, sessionToken: string): Promise<void> { 
  const endpoint: Endpoint = {
    hostname: 'myendpoint-ats.iot.us-east-1.amazonaws.com',
    protocol: 'mqtt',
    port:  443,
    path: '' //not sure if something should go here; it's required for the object but I don't have a value for it.
  };

  const creds: Credentials = {
    accessKeyId: accessKeyId,
    secretAccessKey: secretKey,
    sessionToken: sessionToken
  };

  const config: IoTDataPlaneClientConfig = {
    credentials: creds,
    endpoint: endpoint,
    maxAttempts: 1,
    region: 'us-east-1'
  };

  const client = new IoTDataPlane(config);

  const publishInput: PublishCommandInput = {
    payload: payload,
    qos: 0,
    retain: true,
    topic: 'org/test/topic/<device-specific-id>/status_code' //<> excluded
  };

  const result = await this.client.publish(publishInput); // hangs here

  /* do more stuff */
}
```

It will hang regardless if I run it locally or in the cloud.

Here is the request data formed by the sdk, which looks correct to my understanding:

```
method: 'POST',
hostname: 'myendpoint-ats.iot.us-east-1.amazonaws.com',
port: 443,
protocol: 'mqtt:',
path: '/topics/org%2Ftest%2Ftopic%2Fdevice-specific-id%2Fstatus_code', // same topic but URL encoded
query: {
   qos: "0",
   retain: "true"
}
```

I have also tried rewriting my function to use `IoTDataPlaneClient.send(PublishCommand)` (as described here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-iot-data-plane/classes/publishcommand.html) however that had the same result of a hanging endpoint.